# How can I add PyQt5 QMediaPlayer in Qt Designer?

Tags: python, video, pyqt, pyqt5, qmediaplayer

As title says, how can I do that? Of course, it can be done manually in code, but how can I use Qt Designer with it? Also, I found this unhelpful because it is added in Qt Designer but it won't show in window when Python code is executed: [How to insert video in ui file which made at qt designer?(using python, pyqt5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259825/how-to-insert-video-in-ui-file-which-made-at-qt-designerusing-python-pyqt5)

Comment: what is the problem? the solution works correctly, have you downloaded the example? Why do you say it is not shown? Have you got an error message?

Comment: Explain that, why do not I help you? what happened? I said that it is unhelpful it does not help to understand you.

Comment: I get this: https://imgur.com/a/3piXXDN

Comment: It is possible that problem is in the rest of the code. I'm not very experienced with PyQt5, just trying to do a simple gui for simple program. Can you leave full code from this pic: https://imgur.com/a/3piXXDN, so I can test it with your example?

Comment: That is another problem, think that with your reputation you should know that if you have a problem that indicates that certain code does not work this may be due to your modification, so the correct thing is to publish a [mcve], on the other hand in my answer I gave a link where the example is shown: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47259825, On the other hand, if a solution does not work for you, you should comment to the user who answered before publishing a question.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry. Problem was that I didn't play video and nothing was shown because of that(not even video border) so I assumed it is not here and there is a bug with your solution. I did accept your solution now. Thank you.