# How choose the right column for a comboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel

I have a DB ('texpalsac'), Qtdesigner(ventas.ui) ,a table (products):

```
 PRODUCTS 
COD   NAME
111   bag
112   shoes
121   pants
122   t-shirts
```

I would like that comboBox(comboArt) show the second column ('NAME')   but I dont'n know how to do it. For now only the first column appears ('COD':111,112...).
Thanks

```
class MiFormulario(QDialog, QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MiFormulario, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('Venta.ui', self)

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel (self)
        self.model.setTable ("products")
        self.model.select ()
        self.comboArt.setModel (self.model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `setModelColumn()` method of `QComboBox` to indicate the column you want to display:

```
class MiFormulario(QDialog): # <-- remove QComboBox, it is unnecessary
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MiFormulario, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('Venta.ui', self)

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("products")
        self.model.select()
        self.comboArt.setModel(self.model)
        self.comboArt.setModelColumn(1) # <--- select column 1
```

**Plus:**

If you want to show a QComboBox with 2 columns you must create a custom QComboBox like the one shown below:

**multicombobox.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class CustomView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.setShowGrid(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)

    def adjustWidth(self):
        w = sum([self.horizontalHeader().sectionSize(i) for i in range(self.horizontalHeader().count())])
        self.setFixedWidth(w)
        self.parentWidget().setFixedWidth(w)

    def showEvent(self, e):
        if self.isVisible():
            self.adjustWidth()
        super(CustomView, self).showEvent(e)

class MultiComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def setModel(self, model):
        super(MultiComboBox, self).setModel(model)
        view = CustomView(self)
        self.setView(view)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Text))
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionComboBox()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        if self.model():
            p = self.rootModelIndex()
            t = ""
            for c in range(self.model().columnCount(p)):
                t += " " + self.model().index(self.currentIndex(), c).data()
            opt.currentText = t
            fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font())
            self.setMinimumWidth(fm.width(t))
        painter.drawComplexControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_ComboBox, opt)
        painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ComboBoxLabel, opt)
```

And if you want to use it in Qt Designer you must promote it, for this you can review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259825/how-to-insert-video-in-ui-file-which-made-at-qt-designer).

Comment: Thanks, It works. And how would it be if I needed to show the two columns (COD & NAME) ? The second column only as information.

Comment: @JohnnyPalomino If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank. On the other hand I have no idea how you want to show it, I can think of several devices, so to avoid confusion you could show me an image of what you want to obtain