# Implement function of a widget in PyQt5 without modify the file generated by pyuic5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to add more functionality to a method of a widget but without modify the file generated by pyuic5 because I'm doing modifies in the QtDesigner with frequency so the file is on constant evolution.

I'm thinking in assign a custom function in the Main class to a method that I want grown, for example:

spin.py generated by pyuic5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(257, 181)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(102, 60, 42, 22))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 257, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

[image]

custom .py file spin_main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from spin import Ui_MainWindow
class MainWindow(Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spinBox.mousePressEvent = self.clickEvent

    def clickEvent(self, event):
        print("click event")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this case I want add only the print and that the method continues with its function but with this way I'm cannot keep the previous functionality. What do you recommend me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial solution is to call the base method:

```
def clickEvent(self, event):
    print("click event")
    QtWidgets.QSpinBox.mousePressEvent(self.spinBox, event)
```

But it is not very elegant so I do not recommend it, instead there are other options such as:

### 1. Promotion

You can create a custom QSpinBox and include it in the .ui through QtDesigner(See [1](http://from%20PyQt5%20import%20QtWidgets,%20QtCore,%20QtGui%20from%20spin%20import%20Ui_MainWindow%20%20%20class%20MainWindow(Ui_MainWindow,%20QtWidgets.QMainWindow):%20%20%20%20%20def%20__init__(self):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super().__init__()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.setupUi(self)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.spinBox.installEventFilter(self)%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20eventFilter(self,%20obj,%20event):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20obj%20is%20self.spinBox%20and%20event.type()%20==%20QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.clickEvent()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20super().eventFilter(obj,%20event)%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20clickEvent(self):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print(%22click%20event%22)%20%20%20if%20__name__%20==%20%22__main__%22:%20%20%20%20%20import%20sys%20%20%20%20%20%20app%20=%20QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)%20%20%20%20%20ui%20=%20MainWindow()%20%20%20%20%20ui.show()%20%20%20%20%20sys.exit(app.exec_())) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259825/how-to-insert-video-in-ui-file-which-made-at-qt-designer/47273625#47273625)):

**spinbox.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class SpinBox(QtWidgets.QSpinBox):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        self.clicked.emit()
```

**spin.ui**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="SpinBox" name="spinBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>102</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>78</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>SpinBox</class>
   <extends>QSpinBox</extends>
   <header>spinbox.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

```
pyuic5 spin.ui -o spin.py
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from spin import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spinBox.clicked.connect(self.clickEvent)

    def clickEvent(self):
        print("click event")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### 2. EventFilter

Since what you want is to listen to an event then you can implement an event filter so it is no longer necessary to override any method:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from spin import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spinBox.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.spinBox and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.clickEvent()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def clickEvent(self):
        print("click event")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```